# Moment JS Date and time to timestamp in moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am getting a text value and it is formatted like this : "9/19/2018 10:00 AM".
How would you go about turning this into an epoch timestamp using moment.js or just javascript?

EXAMPLE:

```
console.log(moment('4/17/2018 10:00 AM', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm a').format('x'));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the date string to create a date Object and then use `getTime()` method of the Object.

```js
date = new Date("9/19/2018 10:00 AM");
console.log(date.getTime())
```

Comment: I suggest not to use `new Date` for this kind of input. While it works as the OP expects, it could be not trivial to understand for non-US developers. I think it's better to explicitly tell how to parse the input.

Answer (score 3):

normal js

```
new Date("9/19/2018 10:00 AM");
```

if you want to do with moment js

```
moment("9/19/2018 10:00 AM").unix()
```

Answer (score 3):

The issue in your code is that you are using wrong tokens while parsing your input. Moment token are case sensitive and `mm` stands for `0..59` minutes, `dd` stands for day name (according locale) and there is no lowercase `yyyy` supported.

Use `M` for `1..12` month number, uppercase `D` or `DD` for day of month and uppercase `YYYY` for year as stated in [`moment(String, String)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) docs.

Your code could be like:

```js
console.log(moment('4/17/2018 10:00 AM', 'M/D/YYYY hh:mm a').format('x'));
console.log(moment('4/17/2018 10:00 AM', 'M/D/YYYY hh:mm a').valueOf());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Note that you can use both [`format('x')`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) (returns a `String`) and [`valueOf()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/unix-timestamp-milliseconds/) (returns a `Number`).

I suggest to use [`moment(String, String)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) over `new Date()` (`Date.parse()`) because this way you explicitly state how to parse you input (what would you expect for input like 1/2/2018? 1st of February or January 2nd?). See [here](http://dygraphs.com/date-formats.html) a note about `Date.parse` behaviour

> Somewhat surprisingly, these formats *(e.g. `7/2/2012 12:34`)* are also unambiguous. `Date.parse` favors US (`MM/DD/YYYY`) over non-US `(DD/MM/YYYY`) forms.
>
> These formats may be ambiguous to humans, however, so you should prefer `YYYY/MM/DD` if possible.